# Tslint error when using createBrowserHistory() from @types/history

Tags: typescript, tslint

I am importing the `@types/history` and using the `createBrowserHistory()` function it provides, in my React application.

I get a tslint error saying,

```
ERROR in C:/Users/eshan/my-website/src/App.tsx
ERROR in C:/Users/eshan/my-website/src/App.tsx(13,11):
typedef: expected variable-declaration: 'history' to have a typedef
```

I did look around a bit, but all of the attempts to mitigate this seem to be aimed at removing the tslint rules by doing `/* tslint:disable */`. I would like to add type support, and fix it instead.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component {
  public render(): JSX.Element {
  const history = createBrowserHistory();

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <Router history={history}>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' component={Landing}/>
          <Route exact path='/Home' component={Home}/>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your issue isn't with the `@types/history` library at all. It's that the `typedef` rule is configured in your `tslint.json` settings to require type definitions in places including your `history` variable.

This code would likely also exhibit the TSLint complaint:

```
const createMyHistory = () => ({
    someMember: "someValue",
});

const history = createMyHistory();
```

..because `history` doesn't have an explicit type definition.

Here are two ways you could resolve the error without a `// tslint:disable-next-line`:

- Disable or otherwise configure the `typedef` rule to stop complaining about this case: see https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/typedef/ & https://palantir.github.io/tslint/usage/configuration. This might end up being a part of your `tslint.json`:

  ```
  {
      "rules": {
          "typedef": false
      }
  }
  ```
- Add an explicit type definition to the `history` variable:

  ```
  const history: History = createBrowserHistory();
  ```

Edit: just to add more visibility to what's in the comments below, there are two types/interfaces named `History` at play here. One is the globally defined one that comes with DOM typings. Another is the one that's defined in `@types/history`. It's unfortunately confusing that they both have the same name. If you're seeing errors about `History<any>` not being compatible with `History`, add `History` to your `import` from `history`:

```
import { createBrowserHistory, History } from 'history';
```

That will make your code refer to `@types/history`'s version.

Comment: when I add an explicit type definition to the history variable, as you suggest in the last line, I get this compile time error. 
[ts]
Type 'History<any>' is not assignable to type 'History'.
  Property 'scrollRestoration' is missing in type 'History<any>'.

Comment: Spooky. It might be that there are two types at play: one is the predefined global `History`, and the other is a type inside the `@types/history` definitions that also happens to be named `History`. It's a bit inconvenient how they're named the same thing. If you add `History` to your `import` from `history`, does the complaint go away?